# How do I evaluate this logarithm?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

10^3log2

How do I evaluate it without a calculator?

Comment: Is $\log$ base $10$, and is it $10^{3\log{2}}$ or $10^{3} \log{2}$?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you mean a base-$10$ logarithm and that the exponent is $3\log{2}$, then

$$10^{3\log{2}} = \left(10^{\log{2}}\right)^3 = 2^3 = 8$$